# Unable to include CSS styling in handleBar templates with Node Js App

Tags: html, css, node.js, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I have a Node Js-Express Based app and using handlebars template to design a structure for Nodemailer HTML body. I tried including the CSS file multiple ways for the same, but still none of the styles are being applied to the HTML.

My current project structure is something like this:

```
- backend
  - src
  - helpers
    - templates
      - emailTemplate.handlebars
  - public
    - styles.css
  - app.js
```

The **app.js** is defined to use the handlebars like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

The **handlebar template** goes like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update Project Details</title>
    {{#each css}}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/{{this}}">
    {{/each}}
</head>

<body>
    <h1>{{headerMessage}}</h1>
    <p>{{message}}</p>
    <p>
        {{bodyText}}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="side">
            <button class="edit"> Edit Details </button>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <button class="archive"> Archive Product </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As the nodemailer functions and mail is received, the HTML content is rendered from the HandleBar template inside the mail body, but without any CSS or styling.

I also tried keeping the CSS file inside the same folder as the template, but no luck. Not sure where I'm going wrong. Any help to resolve the same will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the only issue that I see here is the actual linking up of the style sheet to your DOM. If you look at the `app.use` in your app.js where it says:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

that means that any so called "public" files, images, local js, style are stored in the public folder, and that is the new relative path for all headers. So no matter where your ejs or html file is, the relative path to the style sheet will always be from the top level down of your public folder. This makes it more dynamic and the only thing you have to change is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/{{this}}">
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{this}}">
```

Simple as that. Hope this makes sense, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After changing, it still doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: @enthu_dev Hey there, try just doing `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` I dunno what you mean by the `{{this}}` tag so just flush it out with the first section in this comment.

Comment: Still not work. Though I found a weird flex. I inspected the email body HTML in the browser, and seems like even the class="" are removed from every <div> or any HTML tags, forget about including the CSS. Not understanding why is this happening. At least the class names should be there while inspecting the code.

Comment: Hmm, strange. Sorry I can't help you with this one.

Comment: No issues, Thank you anyway for looking into this.

Comment: hey, did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> ` works for me

Answer (score 0):

i used internal style. i placed the css code on the head section it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).